# How to create left navigation using asp.net Menu control with label in between links?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have a left navigation menu where I have 3 asp.net menu controls with 3 sitemaps as below

[image]

Is it possible to achieve this using 1 sitemap and 1 menu control ?

Comment: I have added image to this but don't see that

Comment: sorted the image for you